# How to solve "A SiteDotCom site using template [Build Your Own (LWR)] does not support MD API Retrieval"?

Tags: community, salesforcedx-cli, lwr

I need to retrieve the [SiteDotCom](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm?q=sitedotcom) metadata of a [Build Your Own (LWR)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/intro.htm) community template.

When I run:

```shell
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m SiteDotCom
```

It successfully pulls all the SiteDotCom of Aura templates, but not of the new LWR templates:

```shell
Preparing retrieve request... done
=== Retrieved Source
FULL NAME                            TYPE        PROJECT PATH
───────────────────────────────────  ──────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
auraTemplate1                            SiteDotCom  force-app/main/default/siteDotComSites/auraTemplate1.site
auraTemplate1                            SiteDotCom  force-app/main/default/siteDotComSites/auraTemplate1.site-meta.xml
=== Retrieved Source Warnings
FILE NAME               PROBLEM
──────────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
unpackaged/package.xml  A SiteDotCom site using template [Build Your Own (LWR)] does not support MD API Retrieval.
unpackaged/package.xml  A SiteDotCom site using template [Build Your Own (LWR)] does not support MD API Retrieval.
```

How does one retrieve the [SiteDotCom](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm?q=sitedotcom) of an [LWR](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/intro.htm) template??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, as indicated by the error.

LWR Sites use [ExperienceBundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) by default instead of the SiteDotCom metadata type.

> To use the ExperienceBundle metadata type for Aura-based Experience Builder sites, from Setup, enter Digital Experiences in the Quick Find box, and then select Settings. Select Enable ExperienceBundle Metadata API, and save your changes. **LWR sites use ExperienceBundle by default**.